# DocuSign in COM based environments

Tags: docusignapi

Do you have coding examples integrating to Docusign using a COM based platform.  I have access to SOAP, so any examples in a COM based environment would be helpful.

Comment: What have you tried? "Give me teh codez" isn't a good approach to use here at SO.

Comment: The DocuSign Developer Center contains a wealth of info about the DocuSign APIs (REST and SOAP):  https://www.docusign.com/developer-center    In particular, info about the DocuSign SOAP API is available here:  https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/soap-api

Answer (score 0):

As Kim has mentioned the DocuSign Developer Center has a section devoted to the SOAP API: 
https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/soap-api

On that page you'll see one of the first links guide you to the DocuSign-SOAP-SDK which is up on GitHub:
https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK

Inside the SOAP SDK there are 5 sample projects written in different technology stacks:  `Java`, `.NET`, `PHP`, `Ruby`, and `Salesforce`.  Not only are there working sample apps but there's also code snippet folders you can review.